# Как обновлять/загружать фото на RedBean?

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Всем привет! Есть у меня авторизация пользователя на RedBean,

```
   <?php 


$data = $_POST;
if ( isset($data['do_login']) ) 
{
$errors = array();
$user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login']));
if ($user) 
{
    // логин существует
    if( password_verify($data['password'], $user->password)) {
        // всё хорошо, логиним пользователя
        $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $user;
        header('Location: /'); 
    } else
    {
        $errors[] = 'Неверно введён пароль!';
    }
} else 
{
    $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким логином не найден!';
}


}

?>
```

как осуществить обновление/загрузку изображения в RedBean ?
Нигде в инете даже кода на загрузку нет. На самом сайте RedBean я уже был.

Comment: Изображение лежит прямо в таблице или на диске?

Comment: в таблице и на диске; через php форму загрузки я могу сделать, а вот через RedBean не понимаю как сделать